# Partial application of functions inside a context manager ("with ..")

Tags: python, metaprogramming, contextmanager

Basically, I have an api that provides a class Foo() with some method Foo.bar(arg1, name).

Is there a way to apply a functools.partial object to Foo.bar inside a context manager, i.e. like this:

```
x=Foo()
with my_argument(name="Something") as e:
    x.bar(arg1=5) # == x.bar(arg1=5, name="Something") in this context
```

I wondered if there is a more elegant way for this other than monkey patching Foo.bar ?

*Edit:*
The point is, I have code like this:

```
model.addConstr(a, name="constraint_1")
model.addConstr(b, name="constraint_2")
```

And without additional boilerplate the following code should yield the same calls to 'model':

```
with Arguments(name="constraint"):
    model.addConstr(a)
    model.addConstr(b)
```

Comment: You mean partial application. Partial evaluation is a (usually static, partly because it's rather expensive) [program transformation](http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2012/01/comparing-partial-evaluation-and.html). And if this was possibly you really wouldn't want to do it, except *perhaps* limited to methods of the object that provided the context manager.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you necessarily need the context manager, you can use partial from functools instead:

```
from functools import partial
x=Foo()
_xbar = partial(x.bar, name="something")
_xbar(arg1=5)
```

When you want to "switch context", just redifine `_xbar`:

```
_xbar = partial(x.bar, name="some other thing")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Argumentor(object):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.args = args
    self.kwargs = kwargs

  def __enter__(self):
    return self

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    pass

  def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    newargs = args + self.args
    newkwargs = kwargs.copy()
    newkwargs.update(self.kwargs)
    return func(*newargs, **newkwargs)

def foo(num, name):
  print num, name

with Argumentor(name='bar') as f:
  f(foo, 42)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be rather nicer to have this either take the function as an argument to the manager init, or to have the manager itself return a partially-applied callable?

Comment: @Marcin: What if you wanted to apply it to multiple functions?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams When I say "have the manager itself return a partially-applied callable" I mean that the manager be a callable that takes a function (callable), and returns a partially applied version of its argument.

Comment: @Marcin: The manager is already a callable. We delay acquiring the function so that we can use the returned `Argumentor` instance on multiple functions.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, it's already callable, but I am suggesting that it would be rather nicer if its behaviour were different, so that the invocation of the partially-applied function is by passing arguments to it, rather than by passing the function and arguments for that function to the manager.

Answer (score 1):

Not like that, no. How is your `my_argument` class supposed to know that it's meant to work with `x.bar` without you passing that in? What exactly are the `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods of `my_argument` going to do in this situation?

I don't see why you don't just make a `functools.partial` object for `x.bar` and use that.